¿Cuál es la mejor manera de introducir múltiples datos en un archivo PDF que ya ha sido preparado?
Estoy trabajando en un archivo PDF que contiene un formulario, y estoy utilizando un bucle para introducir datos de una lista llamada detallesPedido. Estoy utilizando el método SetField para asignar valores a los campos del formulario. Me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma de optimizar este proceso ya que estoy generando los campos manualmente y si se llegaran a ingresar más códigos que la cantidad de campos generados no cubriría esa necesidad. Estoy utilizando iTextSharp para manipular el PDF. Agradezco cualquier consejo o sugerencia.

for (int i = 0; i < detallesPedido.Count; i++)
  {
      var detalle = detallesPedido[i];
      string prefix = $"Referencia{i + 1}";

      var referencia = db.RFR_REFERENCIA.FirstOrDefault(r => r.RFR_CODIGO == detalle.RFR_CODIGO);
      string nombreReferencia = referencia?.RFR_NOMBRE ?? "Descripción no disponible";

      decimal precioUnitario = detalle.PEDD_VALOR.GetValueOrDefault();
      decimal iva = detalle.PEDD_IVA.GetValueOrDefault();
      decimal impuestoConsumo = detalle.PEDD_IMPUESTO.GetValueOrDefault();
      decimal precioTotal = precioUnitario + iva + impuestoConsumo;

      totalCantidad += detalle.PEDD_CANTIDAD.GetValueOrDefault();
      totalPrecioUnitario += precioUnitario;
      totalIva += iva;
      totalImpuestoConsumo += impuestoConsumo;
      totalPrecioTotal += precioTotal;

      formulario.SetField($"CODIGO_{prefix}", detalle.RFR_CODIGO.Substring(10));
      formulario.SetField($"DESCRIPCION_{prefix}", nombreReferencia);
      formulario.SetField($"CANTIDAD_{prefix}", detalle.PEDD_CANTIDAD.ToString());
      formulario.SetField($"UND_{prefix}", detalle.PEDD_UNIDAD);
      formulario.SetField($"PrecioUnitario_{prefix}", precioUnitario.ToString("C2"));
      formulario.SetField($"IVA_{prefix}", iva.ToString("C2"));
      formulario.SetField($"ImpuestoConsumo_{prefix}", impuestoConsumo.ToString("C2"));
      formulario.SetField($"PrecioTotal_{prefix}", precioTotal.ToString("C2"));


      string tipoPosicion = detalle.PEDD_TIPO_POSICION == "TAN" ? "Posición Normal" :
      detalle.PEDD_TIPO_POSICION == "TANN" ? "Producto Bonificado" : "Sin especificar";

      formulario.SetField($"TipoDePosicion", tipoPosicion);

  }


Podrías utilizar Reflection para iterar por todas las propiedades de una clase y asignarlas automáticamente. Con esto te ahorras te ahorras parte del problema, el otro problema que genera es que usar Reflection consume recursos, tendrías también que utilizar algún atributo para identificar los campos que quieres que vayan en el reporte.

Por cierto, que no te sorprenda si tu pregunta termina cerrada, de la forma en cual está, no tiene 1 sola respuesta fija, hay diversos caminos y se basa en opiniones. Saludos.
